# Perform segue to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm looking for an answer that I don't find anywhere. I checked every questions but I found nothing. So here is my question:

I have an `UIViewController` where there is a button. This button is supposed to perform a `show` segue: I ctrl+drag the button to a `UITabBarController` in the `StoryBoard`.
What happens: When I touch the button in the `UIViewController`, the first `ViewController` of my `UITabBarController` is presented but there is no `TabBar`. I can't switch to the other `viewControllers`.

I have no code because I did it in the `StoryBoard`.

**My `ViewVontroller` configuration:** 
[image]

Comment: are you embed the second VC in tabbar controller

Comment: Sounds like you may have accidentally ctrl dragged from the button to the first viewController. Try deleting the segue and re-dragging to the UITabbarController.

Comment: No, I have 4 items (viewControllers) linked to the TabBar. I ctrl+drag the button to the `UITabBarController` as show (e.g push).

Comment: Setting up a [storyboard](http://i.imgur.com/s4QrIY6.png) with an interface like you described works just fine with the tab bar displayed. I can't replicate your issue. Maybe try redoing the segue.

Comment: I found the issue: I'm using a custom UITabBar class... How can this custm class can affect the segue?

Comment: What the code for you custom tab bar class? How does it get created? Does it ever get added to the `UITabBarController`?

Comment: In fact, I'm using a custom `UITabBarController` pod that i found on GitHub. This TabBar is working when it is initiate as initial viewController. When I initiate it from a button with a segue, I have this issue... May be I will give up with this...

Comment: Can you show me your connections between the view controller and tab bar controller?